# Java Detect special pattern from long text

Tags: java, android, regex

I am reading text from Aadhar card and Pan card and I am getting below String.

```
छ र्णां ;; _,
ज्यो

हें ष्ठछ्येप् ऽठमांआ (38७/8र्क्स "

  ,; जन्म वर्ष / 78६" ०1‘8६र्णीग् : 1992 खा … खा

पुरुष‘ “'व्'व् हैंप्टेंग्‘

` हु; ";:ळुहुं क्रौं र्मं’फु. ‘_य्; ,; ळु

` हं ` .म्च्हें :: "…. 'दृर्दु‘ऱ्क्ष्क्त

» ॰ -। "' ॰॰ ’ '|’ ""
8471 2211 6099 ,_
```

I have two tasks to do -
1. detect whether it has an aadhar card no or not.
2. if yes then get that no.

Code I have tried

```
 String data = "b dn b fsd b fsd 6666 8888 9999 bsnfbsdb";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "^[a-zA-Z ]*\\d{4}\\s\\d{4}\\s\\d{4}[a-zA-Z ]*$" );
        Matcher m = p.matcher( data );
        if ( m.find() ) {
            String s = m.group(0);
            System.out.println(s);
        }
```

But it is not working, I am getting whole String

Is there is any better solution to do this? or am I doing anything wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What text indicates an "aadhar card?"  Note that most likely you would need to use Unicode/UTF-8 regex to handle this.

Comment: aadhar card is an Indian identity card, I am reading bitmap of it and getting above text

Comment: I suspect you need `Pattern.compile("(?<!\\d)\\d{4}(?:\\s\\d{4}){2}(?!\\d)")`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/MkypoQ/1/).

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
(?<!\d)\d{4}(?:\s\d{4}){2}(?!\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MkypoQ/1/).

**Details**

- `(?<!\d)` - no digit immediately to the left is allowed
- `\d{4}` - four digits
- `(?:\s\d{4}){2}` - two repetitions of a whitespace and four digits
- `(?!\d)` - no digit immediately to the right is allowed

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/PQW3j0):

```
String data = "b dn b fsd b fsd 6666 8888 9999 bsnfbsdb";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "(?<!\\d)\\d{4}(?:\\s\\d{4}){2}(?!\\d)" );
Matcher m = p.matcher( data );
String s = "";
if ( m.find() ) {
    s = m.group(0);
}
System.out.println("Result: " + s); // => Result: 6666 8888 9999
```